# Laravel Collection map - cannot set property to null or false

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-collection

I encountered a very weird issue with Laravel collections. Basically I want to set the **url** and **keywords** properties to NULL if they are empty string.

But for some reason cannot set keywords to NULL or boolean false.

```
$this->feeds = NewsFeed::select(
            ['url', 'keywords']
        )->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->get();

        $this->feeds->map(function ($item, $key) {
            $item->url = null;
            $item->keywords = null;

            return $item;
        });

        dd($this->feeds);
```

And the **feeds** after the map:

[image]

Why the value of keywords is not changing? I can set it to a random string but not null or false. The **url** property is exactly the same type in the DB (VARCHAR, NULL by default).

Comment: did you customize this model with accessors/mutators or anything?  as `null == '' == false`

Comment: Yes, that was it. I had an accessor on keywords I forgot about. Stupid me. 
Write it as an answer and i will accept it.